# Limit of $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to examine whether the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}}$ where $x$ varies on $[-1,1]$ is uniformly convergent or not but rather embarrassingly, I am unable to calculate its limit as $n\to \infty$. I noted that for all $n$, $f_n(0)=0$ and considered two cases of positive and negative $x$. If $x>0$:
$$
0<f_n(x)=\frac{x\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{nx^2+1}}<\frac{x\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{nx^2}}=1
$$
But I have failed to derive anything useful of it. I tried to multiply $f_{n}(x)$ by $\frac{\sqrt{nx^2-1}}{\sqrt{nx^2-1}}$ but it did not help me either. Could you please drop a hint as to what course of action should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the inequality $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \le \lvert a \rvert + \lvert b \rvert$ (which is easily seen to be true by squaring both sides), we see $$\lvert x \rvert = \sqrt{x^2} \le \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} \le \lvert x \rvert + \frac{1}{\sqrt n} \,\,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\,\, 0 \le \sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} - \lvert x \rvert \le \frac {1}{\sqrt n}.$$ The squeeze theorem then shows that $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n} \to \lvert x \rvert$ (uniformly in $x$) as $n \to \infty$.  By limit rules, we see that for any $x\neq 0$, we will then have $$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac 1 n}} \to \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert}$$ as $n \to \infty$, and it is easy to see that $f_n(0) \to 0$ since each element is zero. So the limit function is $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{x}{\lvert x \rvert}, & x \neq 0,\\0, & x = 0. \end{cases}$$ Now you need to decide if the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1/n=0$ then you have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{x}{x}=1$

Edit: I didn’t see @User8128’s comment. When $x$ is negative, we get $-1$ (make a substitution $x\mapsto-x$)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question asks about the limit as $n \to \infty$ not the limit as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @User8128 changed accordingly :)

Comment: But now it is incorrect for $x < 0$...